# VBScript USB CDC communication

Tags: vbscript, usb

Is there a way to set up a simple USB CDC using VBScript?
Regular comm through a FTDI USB-RS232 works fine using

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set com = fso.OpenTextFile("COM7:9600,N,8,1", ForWriting)
```

How, if possible, can i get the same comm with a USB CDC/ACM port? I need booth read and write access.

It is not a drive. It is a device
[USB CDC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUMtx.png) device.
In for example realterm i can access it as an ordernary USB port.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using USB drive?

Comment: What do you mean? I dont follow you.

Comment: When you plug in your USB device, it is mapped to a drive. You can acces a file like U:\Folder\File.txt